# How to add an icon to a flyoutitem?

Tags: xaml, maui, flyout

I have the following code in which I am trying to add an icon to

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Products" Style="{StaticResource ProductFlyout}">       
 <ShellContent Title="Product List" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:ProductsListPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

I have tried adding the following to no success (just providing the general syntax used)

```
<FlyoutItem.Icon> <UriImageSource /> </FlyoutItem.com>
```

```
<FlyoutItem>
 <ShellContent>
        <ShellContent.Icon>
            <Image/>
        </ShellContent.Icon>
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
```

UPDATED

So I have this section at the top that has the title(and the code that defines it). The title appears through the `title` keyword in the `ShellContent` Tag.

I wish for the icon to also appear here, next to the title
[image]

```
 <FlyoutItem Title="Product List" Style="{StaticResource HomeFlyout}">
   <ShellContent Title="Product List"/>
  </FlyoutItem>
```

Not sure how else to add the icon/image. If anyone knows it would be great

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using source in image tag?

```html
<Image Source="0849b3176cec0e8f7fe3.png"></Image>
```

Comment: I have updated my question to be a bit more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `Icon` to the FlyoutItem element. Here is the sample:

```
 <FlyoutItem Icon="image.png" Title="Products" Style="{StaticResource ProductFlyout}">       
     <ShellContent Title="Product List" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:ProductsListPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
```

More information you can refer to [Flyout display options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-7.0#flyout-display-options).

Comment: I have updated my question to be a bit more specific

Comment: This belongs to the navigationpage. You can use the `IconImageSource` to add the icon for the title of page.

Comment: Does this get added as part of the flyoutitem ?

Comment: No, it should be added in the content page.